# MVC API Http Routing

Tags: azure, .net-core, model-view-controller, routes

I have an MVC Web API on the .NET Core 2.2

When I run my API locally, my routes all seem to work fine but when I deploy this to Azure/on my server the routes seem to return a 404 error.

This is my 'PricesController' which has the routes coded in:

```
namespace tf.PriceService.API.Controllers
{
[Route("HorseRacingApi/prices/")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class PricesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPriceService _priceService;

    public PricesController(IPriceService priceService)
    {
        _priceService = priceService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPricesForRace/{meetingDate}/{courseId}/{raceNumber}/{ShowAll?}")]
    public IActionResult GetPricesForRace(DateTime meetingDate, int courseId, int raceNumber, bool? ShowAll = false)
    {
        return Ok(_priceService.GetPricesForRace(meetingDate, courseId, raceNumber));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPriceForEntry/{meetingDate}/{courseId}/{raceNumber}/{horseCode}")]
    public IActionResult GetPriceForEntry(DateTime meetingDate, int courseId, int raceNumber, string horseCode)
    {
        return Ok(_priceService.GetPriceForEntry(meetingDate, courseId, raceNumber, horseCode));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPriceForEntries/{ShowAll?}")]
    public IActionResult GetPriceForEntries(bool? ShowAll)
    {
        string jsonString = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        List<Core.Models.JsonEntryKey> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Core.Models.JsonEntryKey>>(jsonString);

        return Ok(_priceService.GetPriceForEntries(list));
    }
}
```

Using the following URL works locally:
https://localhost:44374/HorseRacingApi/prices/GetPricesForRace/2019-06-24/47/1

but does not work for the Azure version and returns a 404. Am I missing something? Also, the return type is JSON if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please set your web.config as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Somerandomname.WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
```

Further information, you can visit this [link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS).Hope it helps.

Comment: Im sure I have tried this but doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing 'somerandomname' will be the name of the API solution?